# How edit this code to display only one div? Jquery

Tags: jquery

How edit this code, to make, when I click on for example #pizza-show the earlier chosen slide will slide out? 
Now when I click on every 4 functions i can see all 4 slides but I need to se always only one slide. Hop, that I explained this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hamburgery-show").click(function(){
    $("#hamburgery").slideToggle();
  });
   $("#pizza-show").click(function(){
    $("#pizzy").slideToggle();
  });
   $("#piwa-show").click(function(){
    $("#piwa").slideToggle();
  });
   $("#zupy-show").click(function(){
    $("#zupy").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the above code, you can use the `$=` ends with selector:

Inside your click functions, run this line first:

```
$("[id$='-show']:visible").slideUp();
```

This will find all elements that have an ID ending with `-show` (from your code sample) and slide them up before toggling the clicked element. Ideally you should be using a common class on all these elements so you can just call `$(".class").slideUp()` before you take any action on the clicked element.

Comment: Could You past the code? I make something wrong, because this solution doesn't work in my project.